# Types imported from node module becomes `any` after compilation

Tags: typescript, rollup, react-table

I'm trying to use some of the types from another package in my project API because I'm passing those params down to the mentioned package.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
import type { Column, CellProps } from "react-table";

export const foo = (): Column => {...}
```

Everything works fine in the package, but when I build it using rollup, the generated `.d.ts` file looks like the following and the types become `any` when used in any consumer package (and when I hover over them in the `.d.ts` file):

```
import type { Column, CellProps } from "react-table";

export declare const foo: () => Column;
```

P.S.
I'm using rollup for removing the declarations from the code and `tsc --emitDeclarationOnly` for generating those `.d.ts` files.

P.S.2.
I have the `react-table` package in my dependencies which provides its built-in types (I'm not using any `@types/*` package)

Comment: please share tsconfig and your build command.

Comment: The `.d.ts` extract you provided looks fine though... Have you indicated the generated declaration file in your `package.json` (under `types`)? See [Including declarations in your npm package](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't quite right:

> I have the react-table package in my dependencies which provides its built-in types (I'm not using any @types/* package)

The react-table package [does not bundle its types](https://yarnpkg.com/package/react-table?files), but rather provides them on DefinitelyTyped, via [`@types/react-table`](https://yarnpkg.com/package/@types/react-table). If you want the consumer package to have these types, you have a few options.

One is to make `@types/react-table` a dependency of your project:

```
# in your project
npm install @types/react-table
```

Then when the consumer installs your module, they'll pull in `@types/react-table` as a transitive dependency. This has the downside that JavaScript users of your package will have `@types` dependencies that they don't need.

Another is to have the consumer package depend on the `react-table` types via:

```
# in consumer project
npm install -D @types/react-table
```

The downside of this is that your consumers have to manage this dependency themselves.

A third option is to bundle the dependency. This is a good choice if `Column` and `CellProps` are simple interfaces. You could inline their definitions like so:

```
// in your project's TS source
export interface Column {
  // ...
}

export interface CellProps {
  // ...
}

export const foo = (): Column => {...}
```

Assuming your declarations are compatible with the upstream declarations in `react-table`, TypeScript's [duck typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) will make this all work out.

Comment: The types are not simple at all, and we already have an react-table.d.ts similar to what recommended in the @types/react-table docs

Comment: Is your package on npm? I modified my answer to address your comment about react-table bundling its types. This is not the case. If you want the types, you'll need to install `@types/react-table` or provide stubs yourself.

Comment: So there is no way for accessing the types that a dependency package uses. kinda sucks that it doesn't work like that so we have to install the npm package in the dependents. Also, about the point you made on the @types/react-table being a separate package, I wasn't aware of that when I was writing this question but I found out later that I am already using the @types package but I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: This is one of the advantages of DefinitelyTyped (`@types`) over bundling. If `@types/A` depends on `@types/B`, then only TypeScript users will get these packages, and they'll get them via `devDependencies`. When you bundle you have to choose one of the options I listed.